# C regex.h shortest possible match

Tags: c, regex

Suppose I have a string

```
"$Lock EXTENDEDPROTOCOL_verlihub Pk=version0.9.8e|<VerliHub> This hub is running version 0.9.8e (Saturday May 16 2009) of VerliHub (RunTime: 2weeks 6days  / Current user count: 14)|"
```

I am trying to extract the substring

```
"Pk=version0.9.8e"
```

using regexp. Here is my code:

```
regcomp(&regex, "Pk=(.+?)\\|", REG_EXTENDED);
if (!regexec(&regex, buff, MAXMATCHES, match, 0))
{
    regfree(&regex);
    printf("%.*s", match[1].rm_eo - match[1].rm_so, &buff[match[1].rm_so]);
}
```

But the result is

```
"version0.9.8e|<VerliHub> This hub is running version 0.9.8e (Saturday May 16 2009) of VerliHub (RunTime: 2weeks 6days  / Current user count: 14)"
```

How do I find the shortest match?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way I normally do this kind of thing is to have my capture exclude the delimiter character. You could for example use a regex like this:

```
"Pk=([^|]+)"
```

which should capture any number of characters that are not a pipe.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code :

```
regcomp(&regex, "Pk=(.+?)(?:|)", REG_EXTENDED);
```